# Solr Search score is always coming as 0 .0

Tags: solr, scoring

We are trying to evaluate Solr as a search solution and facing issues in retrieving scores. We did crawl and index but all the scores are coming as 0.0 despite that we didn't change any configuration with respect to scoring as per our knowledge.

Would be great if anyone can replicate and let us know the cause here. Would be a great help.

Solr Version is 4.2

Comment: Please post your Schema, Query and a sample output from debugQuery

Comment: Try giving a boost to the documents. That will affect the score. 
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_change_the_score_of_a_document_based_on_the_.2Avalue.2A_of_a_field_.28say.2C_.22popularity.22.29

Comment: PLease find attached configuration files

Answer (score 0):

```
    <schema name="nutch" version="1.5">
    <types>
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />        
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>        
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>       
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>        
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
        <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true"
            omitNorms="true"/> 
        <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0"
            omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
        <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0"
            omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
     <!-- boolean type: "true" or "false" -->
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!--Binary data type. The data should be sent/retrieved in as Base64 encoded Strings -->
    <fieldtype name="binary" class="solr.BinaryField"/>
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tlong" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

    <!-- A general unstemmed text field - good if one does not know the language of the field -->
    <fieldType name="textgen" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>        
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>


    <fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" indexed="true" />   

        <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0"
            omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<fieldType name="fullText" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />        
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>        
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

  <!-- For Spellcheck -->
    <fieldType name="textSpell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>        
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />  
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>  

   <!-- lowercases the entire field value, keeping it as a single token.  -->
    <fieldType name="lowercase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

   <fieldType name="url" class="solr.TextField"
            positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                    generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"/>
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
    </types>
    <fields>
        <field name="id" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <!-- Spellcheck field -->
        <field name="spell" type="textSpell" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" multiValued="true" />
    <!-- For Sorting purpose -->
        <field name="titleSort" type="lowercase" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false"/>
        <!-- core fields -->
        <field name="segment" type="string" stored="true" indexed="false"/>
        <field name="digest" type="string" stored="true" indexed="false"/>
        <field name="boost" type="float" stored="true" indexed="false"/>

        <!-- fields for index-basic plugin -->
        <field name="host" type="url" stored="false" indexed="true"/>
        <field name="site" type="string" stored="false" indexed="true"/>
        <field name="url" type="url" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
        <field name="content" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
        <field name="title" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
        <field name="cache" type="string" stored="true" indexed="false"/>
        <field name="tstamp" type="date" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <!-- fields for index-anchor plugin -->
        <field name="anchor" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"
            multiValued="true"/>

        <!-- fields for index-more plugin -->
        <field name="type" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"
            multiValued="true"/>
        <field name="contentLength" type="long" stored="true"
            indexed="false"/>
        <field name="lastModified" type="date" stored="true"
            indexed="false"/>
        <field name="date" type="date" stored="true" indexed="true"/>

        <!-- fields for languageidentifier plugin -->
        <field name="lang" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
<!-- KS -->
<field name="metatag.description" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
<field name="metatag.keywords" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true"/>

        <!-- fields for subcollection plugin -->
        <field name="subcollection" type="string" stored="true"
            indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>

        <!-- fields for feed plugin (tag is also used by microformats-reltag)-->
        <field name="author" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
        <field name="tag" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>
        <field name="feed" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
        <field name="publishedDate" type="date" stored="true"
            indexed="true"/>
        <field name="updatedDate" type="date" stored="true"
            indexed="true"/>
        <!-- fields for creativecommons plugin -->
        <field name="cc" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"
            multiValued="true"/>

<!-- This field has been added to implement the default search configuration -->
        <field name="text" type="fullText" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" multiValued="true" /> 

<!-- For Extract Handler -->

        <!-- copyField commands copy one field to another at the time a document
        is added to the index.  It's used either to index the same field differently,
        or to add multiple fields to the same field for easier/faster searching.  -->
                <copyField source="anchor" dest="text"/>
                <copyField source="title" dest="text"/>
                <copyField source="content" dest="text"/>
<!--                <copyField source="description" dest="text"/>-->
<!--                <copyField source="keywords" dest="text"/> -->


       <!-- For Spell Check -->
        <copyField source="anchor" dest="spell"/>
        <copyField source="title" dest="spell"/>
        <copyField source="content" dest="spell"/>
        <!-- For Sorting purpose -->
        <copyField source="title" dest="titleSort"/>

 <!-- Dynamic field definitions.  If a field name is not found, dynamicFields
        will be used if the name matches any of the patterns.
        RESTRICTION: the glob-like pattern in the name attribute must have
        a "*" only at the start or the end.
        EXAMPLE:  name="*_i" will match any field ending in _i (like myid_i, z_i)
        Longer patterns will be matched first.  if equal size patterns
        both match, the first appearing in the schema will be used.  -->
   <dynamicField name="*_i"  type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_l"  type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_b"  type="boolean" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_f"  type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_d"  type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_dt" type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

   <!-- some trie-coded dynamic fields for faster range queries -->
   <dynamicField name="*_ti" type="tint"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_tl" type="tlong"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_tf" type="tfloat"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_td" type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_tdt" type="tdate"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="attr_*" type="textgen" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

   <dynamicField name="random_*" type="random" />



    </fields>
    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
    <defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
    <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
    <similarity class="org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.DefaultSimilarity"/>
    </schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Query : select?q=Menu&wt=xml&indent=true&debug=true&fl=*,score

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

−
<response>
−
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">3</int>
−
<lst name="params">
<str name="fl">id,title,score</str>
<str name="indent">true</str>
<str name="q">Menu</str>
<str name="debug">true</str>
<str name="wt">xml</str>
</lst>
</lst>
−
<result name="response" numFound="6" start="0" maxScore="0.0">
−
<doc>
<str name="title">English :: McDonalds.ca</str>
<str name="id">http://www.mcdonalds.ca/</str>
<float name="score">0.0</float>
</doc>
−
<doc>
<str name="title">Corporate Opportunities :: McDonalds.ca</str>
−
<str name="id">
http://www.mcdonalds.ca/ca/en/careers/corp_opp/corporate_opportunities.html
</str>
<float name="score">0.0</float>
</doc>
−
<doc>
<str name="title">People :: McDonalds.ca</str>
−
<str name="id">
http://www.mcdonalds.ca/ca/en/careers/rest_opp/people.html
</str>
<float name="score">0.0</float>
</doc>
−
<doc>
<str name="title">Training, Education and Benefits :: McDonalds.ca</str>
−
<str name="id">
http://www.mcdonalds.ca/ca/en/careers/rest_opp/training_education_and_benefits.html
</str>
<float name="score">0.0</float>
</doc>
−
<doc>
<str name="title">Working Here :: McDonalds.ca</str>
−
<str name="id">
http://www.mcdonalds.ca/ca/en/careers/rest_opp/working_here.html
</str>
<float name="score">0.0</float>
</doc>
−
<doc>
<str name="title">Environment :: McDonalds.ca</str>
−
<str name="id">
http://www.mcdonalds.ca/ca/en/communities/environment.html
</str>
<float name="score">0.0</float>
</doc>
</result>
−
<lst name="spellcheck">
<lst name="suggestions"/>
</lst>
−
<lst name="debug">
−
<lst name="queryBoosting">
<str name="q">menu</str>
<null name="match"/>
</lst>
<str name="rawquerystring">Menu</str>
<str name="querystring">Menu</str>
<str name="parsedquery">text:menu</str>
<str name="parsedquery_toString">text:menu</str>
−
<lst name="explain">
−
<str name="http://www.mcdonalds.ca/">

0.0 = (MATCH) weight(text:menu in 0) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
  0.0 = fieldWeight in 0, product of:
    1.4142135 = tf(freq=2.0), with freq of:
      2.0 = termFreq=2.0
    0.84584934 = idf(docFreq=6, maxDocs=6)
    0.0 = fieldNorm(doc=0)
</str>
−
<str name="http://www.mcdonalds.ca/ca/en/careers/corp_opp/corporate_opportunities.html">

0.0 = (MATCH) weight(text:menu in 1) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
  0.0 = fieldWeight in 1, product of:
    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
      1.0 = termFreq=1.0
    0.84584934 = idf(docFreq=6, maxDocs=6)
    0.0 = fieldNorm(doc=1)
</str>
−
<str name="http://www.mcdonalds.ca/ca/en/careers/rest_opp/people.html">

0.0 = (MATCH) weight(text:menu in 2) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
  0.0 = fieldWeight in 2, product of:
    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
      1.0 = termFreq=1.0
    0.84584934 = idf(docFreq=6, maxDocs=6)
    0.0 = fieldNorm(doc=2)
</str>
−
<str name="http://www.mcdonalds.ca/ca/en/careers/rest_opp/training_education_and_benefits.html">

0.0 = (MATCH) weight(text:menu in 3) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
  0.0 = fieldWeight in 3, product of:
    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
      1.0 = termFreq=1.0
    0.84584934 = idf(docFreq=6, maxDocs=6)
    0.0 = fieldNorm(doc=3)
</str>
−
<str name="http://www.mcdonalds.ca/ca/en/careers/rest_opp/working_here.html">

0.0 = (MATCH) weight(text:menu in 4) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
  0.0 = fieldWeight in 4, product of:
    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
      1.0 = termFreq=1.0
    0.84584934 = idf(docFreq=6, maxDocs=6)
    0.0 = fieldNorm(doc=4)
</str>
−
<str name="http://www.mcdonalds.ca/ca/en/communities/environment.html">

0.0 = (MATCH) weight(text:menu in 5) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
  0.0 = fieldWeight in 5, product of:
    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
      1.0 = termFreq=1.0
    0.84584934 = idf(docFreq=6, maxDocs=6)
    0.0 = fieldNorm(doc=5)
</str>
</lst>
<str name="QParser">LuceneQParser</str>
−
<lst name="timing">
<double name="time">3.0</double>
−
<lst name="prepare">
<double name="time">1.0</double>
−
<lst name="query">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
−
<lst name="facet">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
−
<lst name="mlt">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
−
<lst name="highlight">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
−
<lst name="stats">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
−
<lst name="spellcheck">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
−
<lst name="elevator">
<double name="time">1.0</double>
</lst>
−
<lst name="debug">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
</lst>
−
<lst name="process">
<double name="time">2.0</double>
−
<lst name="query">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
−
<lst name="facet">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
−
<lst name="mlt">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
−
<lst name="highlight">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
−
<lst name="stats">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
−
<lst name="spellcheck">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
−
<lst name="elevator">
<double name="time">0.0</double>
</lst>
−
<lst name="debug">
<double name="time">2.0</double>
</lst>
</lst>
</lst>
</lst>
</response>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had www.mcdonalds.ca domain configurd in my filter. As this was getting redirected to www.mcdonalds.ca.ca/en.html, score was not coming for any of the URL.

I modified the top URL and instead of www.mcdonalds.ca, I did mention www.mcdonalds.ca/ca/en.html and it worked.

Please go through following URL for more details -

http://grokbase.com/t/nutch/user/117cpvp70q/a-possible-solution-to-my-url-redirection-and-zero-scores-problem